# How to create a soft link between root partition and ext3 partition(on SD)

Tags: adb, linux, ext3

I am trying to create symbolic links of `/data/sdext2/app/*` on `/data/app`.
This is what I did in adb shell
`ln -sf /data/sdext2/app/* /data/app/`
But it is telling *"link failed No such file or directory"*.
Note that none of the partitions are of FAT32 format.
And without -f option it says *"link failed File exists"*.

Answer (score 1):

**ln** only takes 2 arguments at most (not counting options), the ../* wildcard however expands to all filenames in the folder. Just do place an echo before ln to see what happens.

Do it one by one this way:

> cd /data/sdext2/app
>   for i in *; do ln -s /data/sdext2/app/"$i" /data/app/;done

or

> for i in /data/sdext2/app/*; do ln -s "$i" /data/app/$(basename "$i");done

EDIT

Ok, this is how it works on my device:

> me@workstation:~$ adb shell
>   shell@android:/ $ id
>   uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell)   groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),[...]
>   shell@android:/ $ su
>   shell@android:/ # id
>   uid=0(root) gid=0(root)   groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),[...]
>   shell@android:/ # cd /data/
>   shell@android:/data # ln -s /data/sdext2/app/banana.app /data/app/cucumber.app
>   shell@android:/data # ls -l /data/app/cucumber.app
>   lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2012-11-06 22:30 /data/app/cucumber.app -> /data/sdext2/app/banana.app

Comment: Will that link hidden files/folders?

Comment: Hehe :-) Of course not, but the original attempt wouldn't do that either (so I didn't bother).

Comment: still same problem.. i can use other apps like root explorer and link2sd to create soft links.. wonder how it is done..

Comment: See my update, also read more on the *ln* command [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln).

Comment: so.. what do u exactly want me to do??

Answer (score 1):

I made it [this way](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1083308)

```
cp -a /sdcard/olivetree /sdcard/sdcard-disk/olivetree
rm -rf /sdcard/olivetree
ln -sf /sdcard/sdcard-disk/olivetree /sdcard/olivetree
```

But for wired reasons it didn't work or me in android 'Terminal Emulator' but smoothly worked from my PC via Putty and android 'SSH Droid'.